# Does a Runnable in AsyncTask block the service/activity? It does for me

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I have a service that executes a huge time-consuming computation. So I added an `AsyncTask` to run it in background. I have the call to `requestLocationUpdates()` which apparently can't be executed in an AsyncTask without a `Looper`. Most suggested against using a `Looper`, for I don't know why. So finally I had to add a `Runnable` in the `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` with a `Handler`. The `Runnable` seems to be blocking the activity that calls this service. This does not happen when my application is minimised. In fact, another activity of my app is also momentarily blocked whenever the execution happens.

**1. What exactly is happening when I call a Runnable on a Handler?**

**2. How do I make it really run in background?**

```
    private void forkAsyncForTracking(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        private Location loc = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loc = getLocation();//this blocks the activity
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void lol){
            doIt(loc);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Maybe the runnable is being used by the handler defined on the main thread. Post some code, it's not possible to help without checking it.

Comment: @gauravjain The handler is a private to this service. Also, I've uploaded the relevant part of the code corresponding to AsyncTask.

Comment: In effect, this code does nothing - the AsyncTask merely puts the Runnable back on the main thread, so it is almost as if neither exists, and you just have the bare call to getLocation().  What you need to do is fix *that* method to separate the main thread operations from the blocking ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a service runs on 'main' thread. So if you declare a handler as a private to the service, it's considered as declared on main thread. Hence, the runnable declared inside the doInBackground will execute on main thread. Remember, it depends on the handler which is posting the runnable on where it'll be executed. You've to declare the handler inside the worker thread (which in this case will be doInBackground method), and also define a looper using Looper.prepare() (since, by default a worker thread doesn't have a looper, so there'd be no message queue which the handler can use). Try this out, and that method shouldn't cause any blocking thereafter.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();                 //Declared on worker thread.
            Looper.prepare();
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loc = getLocation();//this blocks the activity
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
```

Another approach could be to use an IntentService, which runs on a worker thread by default, so you won't need any async task then. For IntentService, check this out : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Yes, but what is missing here is probably that the function in question won't work except when run on the main thread.  Probably what needs to happen is that that function needs to be re-written to separate actions which must be on the main thread from those which block.

Comment: @Chris, you're correct, but that's not evident from the question. Thanks, because it's a nice suggestion which improves upon the answer and will help the OP as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I guess you're right. I need to modify my `getLocation()`. It does require to be run on the main thread, and I'll have to figure out another approach to find location without the main thread.